# How to change link path in certain container with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to change the links in two containers I have from link.php to ../link.php on certain pages.

Can someone help my with the jQuery code I need to do this?

The containers are two divs, one with the id="nav" and one with the id="fnav"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by links, you mean the `a` elements. You can use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), to get a reference to your divs, search for all `a` elements using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and change the `href` with [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('#nav, #fnav')
.find('a')
.attr('href', function(i, value){return '../' + value});
```

You can pass a function to `attr` which gets the old value as parameter. So this prepending all paths with `"../"`.

If you only want to change the links that refer to `index.php`, then use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/): `.find('a[href="index.php"]')`

Comment: But I'm not sure if collusion like that is allowed, hehe. Anyway I can't get more rep for today, I'll take the checkmark!!! ;)

Comment: I tried both this and jAdny's code and it's returning the link as undefined? Looking though the jQuery, it makes sense what's going on so I'm not sure why it's resulting with the link being undefined. For example, if you mouse over a link, the href path is now, domainname.com/undefined  Any thoughts?

Comment: @hybrid: Good question. A [quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/R4vjZ/) shows that the method itself works. Could you post an excerpt of your HTML (just the relevant part)?

Comment: @Felix: Thanks for the quick reply to this. I think I figured out what is causing the issue. I was using jQuery 1.3.2 - Here is a test with 1.3.2 - http://jsfiddle.net/bjankord/yFwxN/ It adds the ../foo/ in yet it doesn't seem to be picking up the href attribute. Instead its results in domainn.com/foo/undefined. I need to update to 1.4.4 anyways yet I am curious why using jQuery 1.3.2 causes the href attribute result as undefined. Thanks!

Comment: @hybrid: Oh yeah that is weird. I extra checked it earlier and the docs says that it is supported since jQuery 1.1.... otherwise, not supported version would have been my first idea....

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty simple:

```
$('#nav, #fnav').find('a').attr('href', function(index, href) {
    return '../' + href;
});
```

Ref.: [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: In case anyone wonders: I did not upvote, I never spoke with jAndy, I don't even know him. Seriously. I just came by here by chance....